# How to identify API usage per custom application

Tags: api, wsdl

I am developing a few applications using the enterprise wsdl.  Is there anyway to identify my applications with a name or ID so I can later track API usage on a per application basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch from the Enterprise API to the the Partner API you can have the client Id specified in the [CallOptions](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_calloptions.htm) header. This appears in the Login History in the Application column. There is no equivalent header for the Enterprise API.

I have seen Salesforce Support capture extended tracing for a period of time, but this isn't a long term monitoring solution.

Otherwise it is generally better if each client application tracks it's own API calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logging in using the username and password flow then no. If you are using connected apps and oAuth then it can be monitored within the native SF ui

Comment: how can it be done using SF's UI? Even better, is there any way to get it through the API?